# How to link entities on active admin using non foreign key fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to create a link to refference another model but i dont have the primary key field available.

I want to create a link in OrderProduct using store_id_product but active admin only uses id_product:

```
            ActiveAdmin.register Product
              index do |customer|
                  column :id_product, :sortable => false (foreign key)
                  column :description, :sortable => false
                  column :url, :sortable => false
                  column :store_id_product, :sortable => false (not a foreign key)
              end
            end


            ActiveAdmin.register OrderProduct
              index do |customer|
                  column :id_order, :sortable => false (foreign key)
                  column :date_order, :sortable => false
                  column :id_customer, :sortable => false
                  column :store_id_product, :sortable => false
              end
            end
```

There's some way to do this??

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the table cell by passing a block to the `column` method.

```
ActiveAdmin.register OrderProduct do
  index do |customer|
    ...
    column :store_id_product, :sortable => false do |order_product|
      link_to 'Product', product_path(order_product.store_id_product)
    end
  end
end
```

If `store_id_product` is not pointing to the primary key in the `products` table then you have to provide a way for the `ProductController` (generated by `ActiveAdmin.resource Product do ... end`) to retrieve the product by that field. You could create a [new custom action](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/abe59fdc6cd73803bd94e6b8403b9df9ec11d947/docs/8-custom-actions.md) or [customize the product's retrieval](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/abe59fdc6cd73803bd94e6b8403b9df9ec11d947/docs/2-resource-customization.md#customizing-resource-retrieval). The second case means that you always want to retrieve the products by `store_id_product`.

Comment: Thanks ! I ended changing the model to use the primary key instead.